# $home_url Value not updated with **company.default.home.url**

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have a scenario where I am successfully able to fetch $home_url in my vm file. But recently I updated **company.default.home.url** in portal-ext.properties from /web/guest to /web/abc/home. As a result $home_url started fetching /web/abc/home instead of /web/guest. Now the problem is, when i reverted back the **company.default.home.url** to /web/guest, $home_url still fetches /web/abc/home.
I tried restarting the server, clearing the browser cache and clearing server cache but still no luck. I can see that changes have been reflected succesfully in System properties in Server Administration section of Control Panel but $home_url is not picking up that value anymore.

I am using Liferay 6.0.6 CE on tomcat 6.0.29.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$home_url returns company home URL if present. If this not existed, then it returns the default value of property - company.default.home.url

Check for entry in table - Company in your database

> select * from Company

This table has column "homeURL", if this has non null value, then $home_url indicates the same.

This "homeURL" can be updated in Portal Settings -> General, Home URL
As you mentioned its empty in your case, You need to provide value here so that it get updated for $home_url.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that your configuration for `company.default.home.url` has been persisted to the database after your change to `portal-ext.properties`. This way, Liferay would always pick up the version from the database, instead of the properties file.

You can check for this value in Control Panel under Portal Settings/General if I remember correctly. If you find the value there, change it there. As it's discouraged to manipulate the database directly, you shouldn't attempt revert it to fetching the file's content.

Comment: Hi Olaf,
All the 3 fields (Home URL, Default Landing Page, Default Logout Page) are empty in Control Panel under Portal Settings/General. Is there any other place where these values persist? In an xml file or somewhere?